# How to select the DOM element from a querySelectorAll NodeList to apply focus()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

See EDITS below for most relevant new information.

Within an angular directive, I have an element that is a div. I am searching for descendents that are inputs and grabbing the first one to apply focus to.

```
var nodes = element[0].querySelectorAll('input, button');
```

I can access the input I want with nodes[0] but I can not figure out how to execute focus() call against it.

```
nodes[0].focus() does not work
$(nodes[0]).focus() does not work
angular.element(nodes[0]) does not work
```

When I print the nodelist to the console:

```
NodeList [ <button.yes.btn.btn-default>, <button.no.btn.btn-default> ]
```

When I select nodes[0] and print to console:

```
<button data-ng-click="showMismatchWarning = false; verifyRentalItemsMatch()" class="yes btn btn-default" type="button" answer="">
```

For example, that's the button I would want to apply focus() to. I just can't seem to figure out how to go from the queryselector result to executing the native html focus()

---

EDIT (MOST RELEVANT INFO):

Further information. I have different tabs so they're hidden. But the directive is applied on the same boolean expression isPage(x) so the DOM elements should be visible by this point in time.

```
<div ng-show="isPage(1)" myFocus="isPage(1)">
  <input> <--- this very first one focus() seems to work
</div>

<div ng-show=isPage(2)" myFocus="isPage(2)">
  <input> <--- this one the focus() never works
</div>
```

Thinking about this more it must be that the focus() is running before the DOM element is fully visible, that's why the focus() is failing. But the directive is $watching on the attributes and watches for this same expression to become true, why would it be executing before ng-show?

Here's my directive for reference.

```
"use strict";
angular.module('something').directive("myfocus", function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            scope.$watch(attributes.focuson, function(newValue) {
                if(newValue) {
                    highlightAndFocus(element[0]);
                }
            },true);

            function highlightAndFocus(node) {
                var task = $(node);
                task.focus();
                task.addClass('highlight');

                var nextInput = node.querySelector('input, button:not(#cancel)');
                nextInput.focus();
                console.log(nextInput);

            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What is `element` here?  Can you post what your nodeList looks like?

Comment: @jmargolisvt updated to include additional information. The element is a div that contains inputs.

Comment: The first one, `nodes[0].focus()`, should work. What happens when it fails? What ends up with focus just after you try to focus the element?

Comment: Are the elements to focus visible? Fwiw, unlike jQuery, in standard DOM you don’t need to select _all_ elements if you need just the first _one_: use `querySelector()` (not `…All()`) — it returns the element itself, or `null` if the element is not found.

Comment: @Douglas nothing gets the focus. It just doesn't seem to execute. So in reality what I'm doing is focusing on the div then applying a class to it, then searching for inputs, then trying to focus on the first input. The class is applied but the focuses don't seem to work except for the very first one.

Comment: I am using ng-show so "pages" are visible. This directive is watching the same expression as ng-show to activate when the page becomes visible. The idea is that when you hit this new page, it's more like a tab actually, then the directive will highlight the div and focus on the input for you. The focus() doesn't work.

Comment: Fwiw, there is a limited set of focusable elements. Afaik, `DIV` is not among those.

Comment: @MaratTanalin I am using tabindex="-1" on the divs to make them focusable. But regardless the selector is querying for inputs so we're talking about input or button and those are definitely focusable.

Comment: For testing, try to delay setting focus with `setTimeout()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131383/discussion-between-marat-tanalin-and-milan-novakovic).

Comment: I think this might be solved by setting a timer (setTimeout) after making the tab visible. The interval can be short, maybe even 0, because you don't actually have to wait. You just have to give the browser a chance to actually make the tab visible. Some browsers (Edge?) will do that immediately and in those browsers your code probably works. Others (Chrome?) need a timeout to get the chance to make the tab actually visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element to focus is apparently not visible at the moment of calling `focus()`. Use a non-zero timeout to delay focusing or a built-in feature (if it exists) of the framework to detect the moment the element gets visible.

Alternatively, try to read the `offsetWidth` (or `offsetHeight`) property of the element to focus, to force page reflow/repaint before setting focus.

Comment: As we discussed, it's not ideal but it appears the only way to get it to work is with some timer period. 10ms seems to always work. Any lower than that isn't reliable.

Comment: You could even consider setting a new timer when setfocus fails. Repeat for a limited number of times, of course...

Comment: As added thought I have lowered the priority level of my directive to -1 because ng-show is 0. This seems to have had some effect because now with 0ms timeout specified it will occassionally set the focus. Unfortunately it still seems that some timeout must be specified...